# How to expand environment variable in bash function definition?

Tags: bash

I am trying to so something like this in my bashrc

```
SERVER=abc.com
geta() { scp ${SERVER}:$1 . ;}

SERVER=xyz.com
getx() { scp ${SERVER}:$1 . ;}

declare -f geta getx
geta () 
{ 
    scp ${SERVER}:$1 .
}
getx () 
{ 
    scp ${SERVER}:$1 .
}
```

What I want geta and getx to be set to is

```
geta () { scp abc.com:$1 . }
getx () { scp xyz.com:$1 . }
```

Is there a way to force variable expansion in function definitions?

Note: For clarification I changed the example

Comment: `ping $SERVER` isn't working for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `eval` (escape the `$` so that `$1` doesn't get expanded)

```
SERVER=abc.com
eval "geta() { scp ${SERVER}:\$1 . ;}"
SERVER=xyz.com
eval "getx() { scp ${SERVER}:\$1 . ;}"
```

The output of `declare -f geta getx`

```
geta () 
{ 
    scp abc.com:$1 .
}
getx () 
{  
    scp xyz.com:$1 .
}
```

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('.                                        eval "function geta() { scp ${SERVER}:\$1 . ;}" works, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to use aliases:

```
get_file() { echo scp "$1":"$2" .; }

SERVER=abc.com
alias geta="get_file $SERVER"

SERVER=xyz.com
alias getx="get_file $SERVER"

geta foo
getx bar
```

outputs

```
scp abc.com:foo .
scp xyz.com:bar .
```

Comment: Almost what I need. I also have `put_file() { scp $1 $SERVER:$2}`. Can't figure out how to use your answer to accomplish that.

Answer (score -1):

```
pserver(){ 
    ping "$1"
}
```

then :

```
pserver abc.com
```

That should do the trick =)